# How to detect coordinates of left and right eye using android face detection

Tags: android, face-detection, eye-detection

Hello I am new to android. I want to detect the coordinates of left and right eye along with hairs in an image.
In this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html#leftEye) it shows that what are the methods to detect eyes that but I am not able to implement these methods.
Also I want to detect the hairs in the image so how can I do that.

Comment: You might try Google's mobile vision API.  This will detect the left and right eyes, although it does not detect hair.  See here: https://developers.google.com/vision/detect-faces-tutorial

Comment: can you please tell me how can i use those left eye and right eye methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the mobile vision API, left and right eyes can be detected as facial landmarks.  See the tutorial for detecting landmarks here:

https://developers.google.com/vision/detect-faces-tutorial

and the API enumerating landmark types here:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/face/Landmark

A slight modification to the code from the tutorial is all that is required to find the eyes specifically:

```
for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i) {
  Face face = faces.valueAt(i);
  for (Landmark landmark : face.getLandmarks()) {
    switch (landmark.getType()) {
      case Landmark.LEFT_EYE:
        // use landmark.getPosition() as the left eye position
```

Comment: Thank you. but i am having a problem in this code
FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
    .setTrackingEnabled(false)
    .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
    .build();
android studio is not recognizing "Builder(context)", so what should i do for this.

Comment: See the answer for setting up Google Play Services: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624827/android-studio-with-google-play-services.  The dependency to add to your build file is "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.+'"

Comment: Hello, i am still not able to use mobile vision. 
I installed : Android support repository, Google play services, Google repository.
i added the latest dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
still it is saying class not found on using "Builder"

Comment: Make sure that your import for the FaceDetector class is the correct one: "import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector;"

Comment: that was the mistake!!. thanks a ton, it was driving me crazy from past 3 days...

Comment: It is still giving me errors :(
Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
 Requesting download for vision face detector
Native face detector not yet available.  Reverting to no-op detection.
creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk
Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
Face detector dependencies are not yet available.

Comment: how will the phone get this library for the first time?

Comment: i followed this answer of yours but could'nt solve my problem....please help me asap...stuck on this from past 4 days...:( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062803/facedetectorhandle-native-face-detector-not-yet-available-reverting-to-no-op-d