# How to calculate length between left eye and right eye using google face API face landmarks in android?

Tags: android, face-recognition, face-api, facial-landmark-alignment

How to calculate length between left eye and right eye using google face API face landmarks in android using the Camera?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34243235/5892625 have you gone through this

Answer (score 0):

Use a face detection API==>  identify landmarks==> Calculate distance between landmarks (coordinates x and y).